# Is it possible to make reusable queries or procs in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

My company's application is designed around large numbers of stored procedures, and the stored procedures are **painfully** non-modular. For instance, a common (anti-)pattern is:

```
IF @param = MAGIC_VALUE_1
  SELECT 20 fields 
  FROM 4 JOINED TABLES
  WHERE SOMEFIELD < 20
ELSE IF @param = MAGIC_VALUE_2
  SELECT 20 fields 
  FROM 4 JOINED TABLES
  WHERE SOMEFIELD < 40
ELSE IF @param = MAGIC_VALUE_3
  SELECT 20 fields 
  FROM 4 JOINED TABLES
  WHERE SOMEFIELD < 60
...3 or 4 more cases
```

The SELECT statements themselves are reasonable business logic, but they can be very complex and repeating them many times like this is horrible for comprehension and maintenance.

I want to refactor logic like this into reusable routines like what you can do in EntityFramework:

```
query = SELECT 20 fields 
FROM 4 JOINED TABLES

IF @param = MAGIC_VALUE_1
  query = SELECT * FROM query
          WHERE SOMEFIELD < 20
...3 or 4 more cases, differing ONLY in the where clause
```

or even better:

```
query = SELECT 20 fields 
FROM 4 JOINED TABLES

query = SELECT * FROM query
        WHERE applyWhereConditionFromMagicParam(query, @param)
```

Is there any way to get even a little closer to this more modular way of composing queries, so I can bring some sanity to our stored procedures?

Comment: Have you considered views and table valued functions?

Comment: @HABO: I know of them, yes, but I'm not familiar enough with their usage to accomplish what I need. Can you suggest how this would work?

Comment: If the main query (select ... from ... join...) repeats, you could create a view to handle that part and reference it as needed. A lookup table or TVF might be a convenient place to bury some of the "magic value" management. (A TVF can be used to provide values for an `in` expression.) Expect to pay a performance penalty for making the code more modular.

Answer (score 2):

In your example I would use a case expression to make this for less painful.

```
Where SomeField < case @param 
                    when MAGIC_VALUE_1 then 20
                    when MAGIC_VALUE_2 then 40
                    when MAGIC_VALUE_3 then 60
                    --etc...
                    end
```

Comment: This is a good way to do this. I would however make the upper bound a variable at the start of the stored procedure and use that variable in the query.

Comment: @TT agreed. Especially as it makes it easy to reuse that value if needed throughout.

Comment: This is much better, thanks. But I'd still like to be able to do this filtering in some sort of reusable routine, because that magic value filtering logic is itself sprinkled through numerous procs, and I'd like to avoid that as well.

Comment: Could you provide more descriptive example of repetitive code? For scalar values filtering there is nothing more to offer.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something but
Just a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) to return an int?

```
query = SELECT * FROM query
        WHERE SOMEFIELD < db.MagicParam(@param)
```

Could also do this with a MagicParam table

Answer (score 0):

you could make a lookup table (whether as a table variable or temp table in the stored procedure, or as a database table), with columns for Procedure name, `MAGIC_VALUE` and value corresponding to the `MAGIC_VALUE`. You could then join to this table in the procedures using the procedure name `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` and the `@param`, to get the value associated with the parameter and procedure.

This approach, while still a bit unpleasant, will let you control the magic centrally and will be a consistent and easy to audit line in all the affected procedures. You could add an error check to see that the procedure name has not changed since the table was updated and that only allowable @param values are provided.